# Why does it take so long to “Set Network Location”?

Tags: windows-7

Whenever I join a new wifi network in Windows 7, the "Set Network Location" dialog box comes up and I choose Home, Work, or Public. But, then it takes maybe 10 seconds for this window to close. What is Windows doing that takes so long on modern computers? Just curious.

Comment: Configuring your network.

Comment: General "configuring" usually just sets a few (or maybe a few thousand) bytes, which should take no noticeable time. I tried to ask this first on Stack Overflow and there was some interest, but it got closed as off-topic there. I think this is a great simple case study for "What the heck is often stalling my computer?"